# Используя powershell, как запустить выполнение кода страницы сайта, который расположнен на удалённом сервере?

Tags: powershell

Есть сайт на тестовом сервере. Нужно с помощью powershell запустить выполнение кода конкретной страницы сайта. 
 Нужно всё это, чтобы автоматизировать процесс запуска этой страницы при коммите. То есть команда powershell будет записана в hook-е.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$HttpContent = Invoke-WebRequest "[http://сайт.который.нужен/страница.которая.нужна](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9.%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0.%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F.%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0)"